# iam getting 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, fetch, mern, user-registration

iam trying to register a user in database using react but iam getting  422 (Unprocessable Entity) error. it works fine in postman

my code

```
client

 const postData = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { name, RegestrationNo, password } = user;

    const res = await fetch("/register", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name,
        RegestrationNo,
        password,
      }),
    });

    const data = res.json();

    if (data.status === 422 || !data) {
      window.alert("registration failed");
    } else {
      window.alert("registered successfully");
    }

    navigate("/login");
  };
```

```
server

const UserRegistration = (req, res) => {
  const { password, RegestrationNo, name } = req.body;

  if (!name || !password || !RegestrationNo) {
    return res.status(422).json({ err: "not filled" });
  }

  User.findOne({ RegestrationNo: RegestrationNo })
    .then((user) => {
      if (user) {
        return res.status(422).json({ err: "user already exists" });
      }

      const newuser = new User({ name, password, RegestrationNo });

      newuser
        .save()
        .then(() => {
          res.status(200).json({ message: "Register successfully" });
        })
        .catch((err) => res.status(500).json({ err: "failed to register" }));
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

please help.

iam getting error  422 (Unprocessable Entity) when i register a user using react

Comment: Did you add the `app.use(express.json())` middleware?

Comment: Yes.. it's working fine now. There was a typo error in model.schema.